# Simple Code in Python, IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, arraylist, indexing

very simple code, and it works. but still have `IndexError: list index out of range` in the second line.

`(if arr[-1] < 0)`

```py
def up_array(arr):
    if arr[-1] < 0 :
        return None
    elif arr[-1] >= 10 :
        return None
    strng= ''.join(map(str,arr))
    strng=int(strng)+1
    new_arr = [int (x) for x in str(strng)]
    return new_arr
```

Could you guys help me, please?

Comment: Could it be that you passed an empty list? In that case, the index of -1 does not exist.

Comment: Thanks ! I will try it !

Answer (score 2):

An `IndexError` happens when you are trying to access a possition in an array that doesn't exist. Since you are using `[-1]` which gets the last item then only way to get an `IndexError` would be that you are passing an empty array. One way to solve this would be to do the following:

```
def up_array(arr):
    if arr==[]:
        print("EMPTY ARRAY")
        return None
    #Rest of your code....
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will try it !

Comment: This assume that arr is always a list; but is not very pythonic where in general we want the function to work with any object that behave like a list but is not exactly of type list (duck typing). So a better solution could be to look at the length of arr to check if it is empty ( if len(arr) == 0: ... )

Comment: or just `if not arr:`

Comment: I made it with putting an empty array thanks guys !